# How to print svg tag element on console

Tags: java, selenium

I want to print my element on the console

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(
    By.xpath("//*[name()='svg']/*[name()='rect' and @height='40']")
);

String val = element.getText();
System.out.println("val");
```

Comment: You should use `System.out.println(val);` instead of `System.out.println("val");`

Comment: try `System.out.println(val);`

Comment: no it didnot print any thing.can you tell me how to print a list of element of svg tag element

Comment: another way
`System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[name()='svg']/*[name()='rect' and @height='40']")).getText());`

Comment: @Shona - did you inspected that xpath is actually pointing to some element

Comment: this one is pointing a line like[ top company avg salary avg experience ]

Comment: make sure you have added wait so that element is added to DOM of the page

Comment: did u mean Thread.sleep

Comment: yes Thread.sleep or explicit wait anything you want.

Comment: ya i add Thread.sleep

Comment: Try the code I posted it will work.

Comment: plz Amit check this link https://careernavigator.naukri.com/sales-executive-retail-careers-in-it-software-software-services i want that topcompany,avg salary,avg exp list on consol

Comment: how do you say a company is top ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be multiple issues like

1. xpath not matching any element
2. wait issue element is not loaded
3. String variable should not be passed in double quotes inside syso

Following code is working and printing around 50 values from table i.e. company name and avg salary

```
public void naukriTest() throws InterruptedException{
    driver.get("https://www.naukri.com/nlogin/login");
    driver.findElement(By.id("usernameField")).sendKeys("validemail");
    driver.findElement(By.id("passwordField")).sendKeys("validpassword");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class='waves-effect waves-light btn-large btn-block btn-bold blue-btn']")).click();
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    driver.get("https://careernavigator.naukri.com/sales-executive-retail-careers-in-mahindra-and-mahindra-financial-services-15731");
    Thread.sleep(18000);
    System.out.println(driver.getTitle());

    List<WebElement> simpleTable = driver.findElements(By.xpath("(//*[name()='svg'])[2]//*[name()='text']//*[name()='tspan' and (@dy='4.40625' or @dy='3.609375')]"));
    System.out.println("size is " + simpleTable.size());
    for (int i=0;i<simpleTable.size();i++)
        System.out.println(simpleTable.get(i).getText());

}
```

Requesting to please do not mark -ve for thread.sleep usage as I am just focusing on finding correct xpath and printing values from DOM.

Comment: thank u @Amit Jain...but this one only showing company list and avg salary...i want avg experience and in lakhs list also

Comment: can u plz tell me xpath for  list of comapany ,avg exp ,avg salary,in lacks

Comment: plz somebody help me for finding xpath for comapny list ,avg exp,avg sal,in lacks list...from last 2 day i tried this one ..but didnot got it

Comment: i got this (//*[name()='svg'])[2]//*[name()='text' and @y='52'] but this one only give me 1st line .i want all the line

Comment: I have updated answer pls check now it prints all values as you needed. I have also pasted xpath you required here.
`(//*[name()='svg'])[2]//*[name()='text']//*[name()='tspan' and (@dy=4.40625 or @dy='3.609375')]`. Thanks, I also learnt about handling `svg` elements.

Comment: i need another help....plz help me...i get this in consol...but if i write in excel sheet it didnot write in excel sheet

Comment: List<WebElement> simpleTable = driver.findElements(By.xpath("(//*[name()='svg'])[2]//*[name()='rect' and @height='40']"));
     List<WebElement> simpleTable1 = driver.findElements(By.xpath("(//*[name()='svg'])[2]//*[name()='text']//*[name()='tspan' and (@dy=4 or @dy='3.5')]"));
     for (int i=0;i<simpleTable.size();i++) {
         XSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(i);
         for(int j=0;j<4;j++) 
   {
    Cell cell1 = row.createCell(j); 
    cell1.setCellValue(simpleTable1.get(i).getText());

Comment: see amit my code is this...but it didnt create excel sheet  in the given format

Comment: plz someone plz help...i need ur help

Comment: Please accept this answer and create new question with more details